# my comments are not showing

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm in a bit of trouble. My comments wont show, I have checked my `comments.php` but I don't see the reason why? Everything was going well last week and then suddenly it doesn't show.

My code is

```
<?php

if ( post_password_required() ) {
    return;
}
?>

<div id="comments" class="comments-area">

    <?php 
    if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
        <h2 class="comments-title">
            <?php
                $comments_number = get_comments_number();
                printf('Comments:');
            ?>
        </h2>

        <ol class="comment-list">
            <?php
                wp_list_comments( array(
                    'style'       => 'ol',
                    'short_ping'  => true,
                    'avatar_size' => 42,
                    'type' => 'comment'
                ) );
            ?>
        </ol>

    <?php endif;?>

    <?php
        if ( ! comments_open() && get_comments_number() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) ) :
    ?>
        <p class="no-comments"><?php _e( 'Comments are closed.', 'twentysixteen' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
        comment_form( array(
            'title_reply_before' => '<h2 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title">',
            'title_reply_after'  => '</h2>',
        ) );
    ?>

</div>
```

On my post template is

```
<?php

get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area main-template-content-post">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <?php single_blog_loop();?>
        <?php comments_template();?>
    </main>

</div>
<?php get_sidebar();?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I've tried include `comments.php` but that didn't work out. Am I missing something? I googled for answers but nothing seems to work. I have been stuck on this since this morning. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Should `get_header(); ?>` be `<?php get_header(); ?>`?

Comment: oh, it is, i just forgot to copy that here. wait, ill edit

Comment: Do you get any JS errors? If not we have to look for an error inside the php part.

Comment: @Glufu i solved it now, but thanks anyway. I figured out that it wasn't the comments.php that i have problems with. It was because i have so many loops in my single_blog_loop() function. I added wp_reset_query at the end of every loop and it works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it wasn't the comments.php that i have problems with. It was because i have so many loops in my single_blog_loop() function. I added wp_reset_query at the end the loop i use to get the post titles for the post article list and it works just fine. here's my code now, it's a bit messy though. I

```
<?php while (have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
        <h1 style="line-height: 40px;" class="heading"><?php the_title();?></h1>
        <h4 style=" margin:0;    display: inline-block;"><?php the_date();?></h4>
        <?php if (get_comments_number() == 1 ) {
                echo ' <h4 style="float:right; margin:0;    display: inline-block;">' . get_comments_number() . " comment in this article</h4>";
            }elseif (get_comments_number() > 1) {
                echo ' <h4 style="float:right; margin:0;    display: inline-block;">' . get_comments_number() . " comments in this article</h4>";
            }else{
                echo ' <h4 style="float:right; margin:0;    display: inline-block;">There are no comments in this article.</h4>';
            }?>

        <?php the_content();?>

        <div class="article-sidebar-container">
            <h4>You might also like:</h4>

        <?php $article = new WP_QUERY(

            array(

                'post_type' => 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => 5

            )

        );

        while ($article->have_posts() ) : $article->the_post();?>

            <div class="sidebarWidget-article">

                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {?>
                    <span style="padding-right: 10px;"><img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url();?>" width="50" height="50"><a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>"><?php echo the_title();?></a>
                <?php }else{?>
                    <span style="padding-right: 10px;"><img src="http://www.papayaleavestea.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/no-image-available-300x200.png" width="50" height="50"></span><a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>"><?php echo the_title();?></a>
                <?php }?>
            </div>

            <div class="pagination"></div>

        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_query();
        ?>

        </div>
        <?php if ( is_singular( 'attachment' ) ) {
            // Parent post navigation.
            the_post_navigation( array(
                'prev_text' => _x( '<span class="meta-nav">Published in</span><span class="post-title">%title</span>', 'Parent post link', 'papayatea' ),
            ) );
        } elseif ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
            // Previous/next post navigation.
            the_post_navigation( array(
                'next_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">' . __( '', 'papayatea' ) . '</span> ' .
                    '<span class="screen-reader-text-next">' . __( 'Next post:', 'papayatea' ) . '</span> ' .
                    '<span class="post-title">%title</span>',
                'prev_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">' . __( '', 'papayatea' ) . '</span> ' .
                    '<span class="screen-reader-text-prev">' . __( 'Previous post:', 'papayatea' ) . '</span> ' .
                    '<span class="post-title">%title</span>',
            ) );
        }?>
        <div class="clearfix spacer pagination"></div>
```